# Асинхронная запись в SerialPort

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, port

Всем привет. Есть небольшое приложение на WinForms, которое принимает значения и отправляет их по SerialPort. Приложение не большое и данные отправляются не часто, но все равно GUI зависает. Было принято решение сделать очередь из пакетов, добавляя их асинхронно и наблюдателя в новом потоке, который в бесконечном цикле отправлял бы значения из очереди. Реализация вышла следующей:

Наблюдатель за очередью пакетов

```cs
public Queue<string> Packages;
private void SendPackages()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (Packages.Count == 0) continue;
        var package = Packages.Dequeue();
        Port.Write(package);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

И асинхронное добавление пакетов в очередь:

```cs
public async Task AddPackage(string package)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Packages.Enqueue(package));
}
```

Теперь при отправке пакетов GUI не подвисает, но наблюдатель отправив несколько значений, не отправляет больше. 
Правильном ли я направлении мыслю? Если да, то как правильно это все реализовать. Если нет, то как лучше это все сделать?

Comment: 'Packages' это что?

Comment: @Vasek Самая обычная очередь: public Queue<string> Packages;

Comment: Не думаю, что добавление элементов в очередь, слишком затратная работа, чтобы крутить ее асинхронно. Может стоит сам цикл закинуть в асинхрон? Так же обратите внимание на условие внутри цикла, я думаю, что у вас 20-30% загруженность ЦП при условии, что пакетов в очереди нет.

Comment: 1)Обычный queue не потоко безопасен. Используйте BlockingCollection. 2) Добавление в очередь элемента быстрая операция не надо заполнять её в асинхронном методе.

Comment: @Vasek Хорошо, попробую сделать иначе. У меня в начале идет проверка устройства, отправка двух значений без задержки. Без очереди данные терялись. Данные так же терялись, при отправке 2 значений без задержки, если метод добавления в очередь был не асинхронный.